# Method File.listFiles(FilenameFilter) not applicable for Predicate

Tags: lambda, java-8, predicate

Consider the following code:

```
File f = new File(".");
Predicate<File> notDir = (File ff) -> !ff.isDirectory();
File [] dirs = f.listFiles(notDir);
Arrays.asList(dirs).stream().forEach(System.out::println);
```

Which gives the following compile time error:

> The method listFiles(FilenameFilter) in the type File is not
>   applicable for the arguments (Predicate)

However, the following code works fine:

```
File f = new File(".");
File [] dirs = f.listFiles((File ff) -> !ff.isDirectory());
Arrays.asList(dirs).stream().forEach(System.out::println);
```

Question: why is this? Aren't the above two snippets equivalent? (Well, probably not, so maybe the right question is: what is the difference between the two?)

(Remark: I know that in the second case, the `File` type declaration coould be omitted in the predicate `(File ff) -> !ff.isDirectory()`, but I think that does not matter for the question.)

Comment: If you want to use a `Predicate`, use `Predicate<Path> notDir=p -> !Files.isDirectory(p); Files.list(f.toPath()).filter(notDir).forEach(System.out::println);` or skip the legacy `File` use completely: `Files.list(Paths.get("")).filter(notDir).forEach(System.out ::println);`

Answer (score 4):

The first snippet doesn't work because there is no overload of `listFiles` that accepts a `Predicate<File>` as a parameter.

The second snippet works because `FileFilter` is a functional interface and you can create one via a lambda expression.  So the second snippet is actually equivalent to:

```
FileFilter notDir = ff -> !ff.isDirectory();
File [] dirs = f.listFiles(notDir);
```